# Is this a valid usage of Promise.all with .then/.catch? (any alternatives?)

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I noticed that a function takes a long time to execute, so I wanted to improve its performance.

I have something like this:

```js
for (item of items) {
  /*

  related logic lines

  */

  /*
  
  related logic lines
  
  */

  try {
    const orders = await getOrders();

    // do some logic with orders
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in orders");
  }

  try {
    const collections = await getCollections();
    
    // do some logic with collections
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error in collections");
  }
}
```

The code above will be slow obviously, since it waits two times for orders and collections then executes the logic that depends on them.

Instead, I tried this:

```js
const ordersPromises = [];
const collectionsPromises = [];
for (item of items) {
  /*

  related logic lines

  */


  /*

  related logic lines

  */


  ordersPromises.push(
    getOrders
      .then((orders) => {
        // do some logic with orders
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error in orders");
      })
  );

  collectionsPromises.push(
    getCollections
      .then((collections) => {
        // do some logic with collections
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log("error in collections");
      })
  );
}

await Promise.all(ordersPromises);
await Promise.all(collectionsPromises);
```

Is the second snippet correct in terms of Javascript? Will it work how I expect it to work? Any disadvantages here, like would it execute twice or more? What alternatives are available?

Comment: If something that your code is *calling* takes a long time, then calling the same API in a slightly different way will make absolutely no difference.

Comment: `Promise.all` is usually used for an array of `promises` to run them in parallel.

For example, I'd expect to see something like `await Promise.all([ordersPromise, collectionsPromise])` instead of still waiting for the 2 promises to execute

Comment: @Pointy  But that depends also on whether the parts inside the loop depend on each other or not. If they were unrelated, I could have used a Promise.all to do them at once, which would be faster overall.

Comment: I'd look at the API call itself. Human-wise, it shouldn't make much of a difference so that means your API is slow somehow

Comment: @Luke So you're saying that a Promise chained with .then and .catch can't be used inside Promise.all?

Comment: @aymcg31 But executing both getOrders and it's calculations with getCollections and it's calculations at the same time, will be faster. Instead of waiting for each one to finish one by one.

Comment: @jabaa Could you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Does anybody know the effect .then/.catch make to a promise while being inside Promise.all?

Comment: @jabaa It's not just a single promise, notice the wrapping forof loop. Each array will have multiple promises.

Comment: Didn't see the loops. Yes, your code is correct. It triggers all functions and waits for all promises to resolve. It's not really clear what you're actually asking. Do you expect an answer like "Yes, your code is correct. There aren't any disadvantags." or "No, it's not correct"? Asking for a list of alternatives is off-topic.

Comment: @OmarDulaimi `.then` and `.catch` work just fine in this way, since both of them return a new promise. `.then` returns a promise that resolves with whatever the closure returns (may be `undefined`) and `.catch` returns a promise that _resolves_ (not rejects) with whatever the closure returns. If either closure throws instead of returns, the resulting promise is rejected and that rejection is propagated, causing `await Promise.all` to throw. That's no different from your original version though.